# What is the origin of the inertia tensor in URDF

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The URDF specifications for a link require that the origin of the inertial frame must be located at the center of gravity of the link. ([urdf/XML/link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Link))

What is the origin of the 3x3 rotational inertia matrix? Is it

1. the origin of the inertia frame, which is also the center of gravity, OR
2. the origin of the link reference frame.

The inertia matrix will be different depending on whether it is calculated with respect to 1 or 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11407/what-is-the-origin-of-the-inertia-tensor-in-urdf/) by [twong](https://answers.ros.org/users/945/twong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I imagine that its (1) but I'm unfamiliar with the actual implementation to back that up.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-11-03**:
Yes, it is indeed (1): the inertia matrix is specified in the inertia frame. I updated the wiki documentation.